# How does a molecule search work by drawing in visual editor?

Tags: molecules, cheminformatics

There are a lot of chemical search engines (such as ChemSpider's 
Structure search) that allow users to draw and search for a molecule. How does it work? Is the comparison of images used? Could you give me an algorithm or pseudo code?

Comment: That title had me confused a bit. How does a molecule search work? It doesn't, it molecules...

Comment: This [site](http://depth-first.com/articles/2010/10/20/how-to-enable-exact-structure-search-and-substructure-search-for-your-chemical-database/) gives a pretty in depth explanation on how these work and has a [series on how to develop such a search engine](http://depth-first.com/articles/2008/10/02/fast-substructure-search-using-open-source-tools-part-1-fingerprints-and-databases/)

Answer (score 12):

Usually, structure search is implemented using a graph model. For example, let's take cyclohexane. On screen this is a hexagon - but this is converted on the server to a simple atom/bond graph model of six carbons in a ring.

This graph can then be compared to all the molecules in the database by various means. For example, subgraph isomorphism or fingerprints or even SMILES string comparison.

As far as I know, ChemSpider allows a variety of searches - with/without hydrogens, substructure search, element fingerprints, and so on. Each of these is a whole question by themselves, so I'm not sure how useful an algorithm that covers them all would be.

Answer (score 6):

Using image based search wouldn't work very well since the same compound can be drawn in a lot of different and correct ways. However, it is possible to convert drawn structures or even 3D structures into text, for example using [SMILES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system) or [InChI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Chemical_Identifier). Those can then be used for standard text based database search.

Answer (score 4):

ChemSpider likely has an algorithm that takes the image and converts it to a SMILES string. It would likely have to do so in order to avoid problems in how the structure is drawn as @DSVA pointed out.

For example, if there's a large molecule (where there could be on the order of billions of slight conformational differences), it would be nearly impossible to find a perfect match in the database. However, by considering only the connectivity of atoms (as a SMILES string would achieve), the software could find a match nearly instantaneously.

ChemSpider has an option on their website to search using a SMILES string, so it's known that their software is capable of recognizing SMILES strings. However, I was unable to find confirmation as to whether SMILES is used as a search method as their software does not appear to be open-source.